# Problem in calling delete action using Ajax in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ajax for calling a delete action in my web api controller.I have problem with two types of calling my api with Ajax.

Here is my api code:

```
[Authorize]
public class AttendancesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AttendancesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int gigId)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var attendance = _context.Attendances.SingleOrDefault(a => a.GigId == gigId && a.AttendeeId == userId);

        if (attendance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Attendances.Remove(attendance);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When I use this javascript code my action call and everything is ok.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/api/attendances/?gigId=" + button.attr("data-gig-id"),
 method: "DELETE"
 })
 .done(function () {
     button
     .removeClass("btn-info")
     .addClass("btn-default")
     .text("Going ?");
      })
 .fail(function () {
      alert("Something is failed!");
});
```

But when I use this code, my api doesn't call and the fail callback method executes.

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/api/attendances/" + button.attr("data-gig-id"),
 method: "DELETE"
 })
 .done(function () {
   button
   .removeClass("btn-info")
   .addClass("btn-default")
   .text("Going ?");
    })
 .fail(function () {
    alert("Something is failed!");
  });
```

I'm confused because the second calling approach used in a learning movie and it works.

Can you explain this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a route to the action in your controller

```
[Route("attendances/{gigId}")]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int gigId)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Thak you Rik Maton

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

The problem is in the definition of **Delete** method, according to the **WebApiConfig.cs** the acceptable route has this pattern: *api/{controller}/{id}*

So the input variable name should be **id** instead of **gigId**.

This is right code:

```
[HttpDelete]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
{
   var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
   var attendance = _context.Attendances.SingleOrDefault(a => a.GigId == id 
    && a.AttendeeId == userId);

 if (attendance == null)
 {
     return NotFound();
 }

 _context.Attendances.Remove(attendance);
 _context.SaveChanges();

 return Ok();
}
```